# How can I define global variables which were defined in previously loaded javascript in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, migration, babeljs

I have a plan to migrate all javascript files into typescript. There are more than 100 javascript files in our system, I had to compile them with tsc , after that renamed their extension into ".ts", in the next steps I need to fix the new bugs, but not sure how can I deal with them. (I have followed the steps from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html)For example, in most of the javascript codes, a variable from previously loaded js is called, and now those variables have errors in new ts , besides that there are lots of errors for external libraries like "i18next".
How can I define global variables which were defined in previously loaded javascript? and also the new typescript does not have an export for their variables and functions, how can import into another ts files?

Comment: You can install the `@types` packages for external libraries. You import and export the same way in TS as in JS, I'm not sure why that got removed.  You probably want to stay away from global variables, but if they cannot be avoided you can declare properties on the type of `window` or use [Webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).

Comment: Thanks @LindaPaiste, All my Js files are implemented by es5, and they are used inside the jsp pages, hence, they are loaded by the defined orders in jsp. I am going to convert all those js files into ts, and then I need to create a bundle.js by webpack which can be used in all the jsp pages. After compiling those javascript by tsc, they don't have export/import like normal typescript files, and there are lots of errors because of using functions/variables defined in previously loaded js.

Comment: If It needs to manipulate created typescript files, should I add import/export for each variable/function which are used in another typescript?